# C++ - map - error: request for member 'first' in 'w', which is of non-class type 'const int'

Tags: c++, dictionary, associative-array

I am trying to make use of maps in C++ as associative containers.  I copied this example directly out of [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, size_t> word_count;
    string word;

    while (cin >> word)
        ++word_count[word];
    for (const auto &w : word_count)
        cout << w.first << " occurs " << w.second << ((w.second > 1) ? " times" : " time") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try and run it, I get "error: request for member 'first' in 'w', which is of non-class type 'const int'".  The authors of C++ Primer are stated as using GNU 4.7.0.  I've tried using minGW ( TDM-GCC-32 ) and Visual C++ 14.  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide real code.

Comment: This compiles on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) with both GCC and Clang.

Comment: Make sure your compiler is set to C++11 mode.

Comment: Using `g++` without `-std=c++11` produce the same error: _error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘w’, which is of non-class type  const int_

Comment: The problem was that the IDE I am using ("CodeLite") does not include C++11 features by default.  Thank you all.

Comment: vc++ 14 should support this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not compiling with a new enough of version of the language standard.

If you were compiling with say, **C++98**, you would see the following:

```
g++ -std=c++98 -o main a.cpp                                                                                                                       1
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:15:22: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘w’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     for (const auto &w : word_count)
                      ^
a.cpp:15:26: warning: range-based ‘for’ loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
     for (const auto &w : word_count)
                          ^
a.cpp:16:19: error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘w’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
         cout << w.first << " occurs " << w.second << ((w.second > 1) ? " times" : " time") << endl;
                   ^
a.cpp:16:44: error: request for member ‘second’ in ‘w’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
         cout << w.first << " occurs " << w.second << ((w.second > 1) ? " times" : " time") << endl;
                                            ^
a.cpp:16:58: error: request for member ‘second’ in ‘w’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
         cout << w.first << " occurs " << w.second << ((w.second > 1) ? " times" : " time") << endl;
```

This is due to the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) introduced in **C++11**.
Try compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main a.cpp
```

(Of course it depends on what compiler you are using)